# How to install Widevine CDM with Chromium on macOS?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extensions

I have just built the binary for Chromium. I am looking to install widevine. How might I do that?

I have only found tutroials for linux https://github.com/proprietary/chromium-widevine.

Comment: You could use Chromium with Widevine built in. Different version of Chromium Binaries are available at https://chromium.woolyss.com/

Comment: @Volsk I need to build chromium, not just install it.

Comment: @JBis the build instructions are tiny shell scripts.  did you try running the scripts line by line yourself ? make sure not to break anything, so make a copy of the project. And remember the symlinks made too. I've never done anything on chrome, so don't know how much the code differs.

Comment: @ankii hmm. I took a look at some of the build instructions there. Compiling now, will check back once it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to successfully install Widevine by adding the following arguments to my build config:

```
ffmpeg_branding="Chrome"
proprietary_codecs=true
enable_widevine=true
```

First and second one makes sure that the codecs are available to play most video. `enable_widevine` well enables widevine.

Once built, go to `chrome://components` and scroll to the "Widevine" one. It should list the version as "0.0.0.0" or something like that. Click "Update". This should change the numbers to the most current version and install it. Restart the browser and it should work.